# Add a string between every characters in a string in Scala

Tags: string, scala

Having a string I would be able to add any string between every characters (not at the beginning and end). For example:

Having string `"abcd"` and adding string `" - "` should give the following `result`:

```
val s = "abcd"
val result = "a - b - c - d"
```

What would be the recommended way to accomplish it in Scala?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply

```
"abcd".mkString(" - ")
// "a - b - c - d"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
s.toCharArray.mkString(" - ")
```

Comment: Or even just `s.mkString(" - ")` :)